# What does the word "contrapuntal" mean here?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> During the above swift flood of words, Brick has reclined with
> contrapuntal leisure on the snowy surface of the bed and has rolled
> over carefully on his side or belly.

This is a stage direction from Tennesee Williams's *Cat on a hot tin roof*.

I looked it up in the dictionary, it says "**contrapuntal**" is a music term and means having two or more tunes played together to form a whole.
I am still confused with the meaning of the word in the quoted sentence.
Thank you so much for replying below!

Comment: Hello Winnie,  Youve quoted a story, Please tell us the source of the story: Title, author and if possible link.

Comment: Found it.  I'll add a citation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a metaphor.  Counterpoint in music is a voice that sings a different melody to the main melody, but harmonises with it.

Metaphorically, Bricks relaxed way of lying on the bed is a counterpoint to Maggie's outburst.  It is different, even contrasting with Maggie's attitude, but in some artistic way, it should harmonize with it to form a whole scene on stage.

There are essays that can, and have, been written about Willams's use of poetry even in the stage directions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Now I've fully understood the meaning of "contrapuntal" here. I have to say William's wording is really beautiful.